# Why ASTRewrite works only when the source files are open in the editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to build a plugin which parses all the files of a project and makes some changes to it, I'm able to make the changes, but my problem is ASTRewrite makes changes only to the files opened in the editor. Is there a way to make the changes to all the files even if they are not opened in the editor?
Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here is the sample code which I'm using:

```
                //create a ASTRewrite
                        AST ast = cu.getAST();
                        ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create( ast );

                        //for getting insertion position
                        TypeDeclaration typeDecl = (TypeDeclaration) cu.types().get( 0 );
                        MethodDeclaration methodDecl = typeDecl.getMethods()[ 0 ];
                        Block block = methodDecl.getBody();
                        block.accept( new ASTVisitor(){
                            @Override
                            public boolean visit( InfixExpression node ){

                                //filter only those compound statements which start with logger
                                if( node.getParent().toString().startsWith( varLogger ) ){ 
                                    loggerStmtList.add( node );



                                    //checking if left operand is present in the logger infix statement
                                    if(node.getLeftOperand() != null) {
                                    //adding '[' to the leftOperand before "
                                        Expression leftOperand = node.getLeftOperand();


                                        StringBuilder leftOp = new StringBuilder(leftOperand.toString());
                                    char[] c = {' ', '['};
                                    leftOp.setCharAt(leftOp.toString().length() - 2, '[');
                                    //leftOp.insert(leftOp.toString().length()-1, c);



                                    //adding '[' the left operand source code

                                    InfixExpression placeHolder2 = (InfixExpression) rewriter.createStringPlaceholder( leftOp.toString() , ASTNode.INFIX_EXPRESSION );
                                    rewriter.replace( node.getLeftOperand(), placeHolder2, null );

                                }

                                    //checking if right operand(extended operand) is present in the logger infix statement
                                    if(! node.extendedOperands().isEmpty()){

                                    //adding ']' to the rightOperand after "    
                                    List<String> rightOperand = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    rightOperand.add(node.extendedOperands().get(0).toString());
                                    StringBuilder rightOp = new StringBuilder(rightOperand.get(0).toString());

                                    rightOp.setCharAt( 1, ']');


                                    //adding ']' in the Extended operands(right side) source code
                                    ListRewrite listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(node, InfixExpression.EXTENDED_OPERANDS_PROPERTY);
                                    InfixExpression placeHolder = (InfixExpression) rewriter.createStringPlaceholder( rightOp.toString() , ASTNode.INFIX_EXPRESSION );
                                    listRewrite.replace( (ASTNode) node.extendedOperands().get( 0 ) , placeHolder , null );  
                                    rightOperand.clear();
                                    }



                                    TextEdit edits;
                                    try{

                                        edits = rewriter.rewriteAST();

                                        // apply the text edits to the compilation unit
                                        Document document = new Document(unit.getSource());
                                        edits.apply(document);

                                        // this is the code for adding statements
                                        unit.getBuffer().setContents(document.get());

                                        System.out.println("rewriting done");
                                    }
                                    catch( JavaModelException | IllegalArgumentException | MalformedTreeException | BadLocationException  e ){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                                 return false;
                            }

                        } );
```

Comment: The [JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Frewrite%2FASTRewrite.html) for ASTRewrite doesn't mention an editor at all. So what makes you think it requires a file open in an editor?

Comment: Because, when I'm executing it it is only making changes to the files open in the editor. The ones which are not have no effect on them

Comment: @greg-449 this is the code i'm currently using to modify the source files